# Indian on F1 in the US, traveling to Sweden, question about passport validity

Tags: usa, passports, indian-citizens

I am a graduate student in the US on an F1 visa (2017-2022). My Indian passport expires on 20th January 2019.

I need to travel to a conference held at Sweden on a Schegen visa. The dates are likely to be July 11th, 12th and 13th of 2018. Their rules require only 3 months of passport validity beyond the intended duration of stay. My intended duration is likely to be 2 or 3 days. So I am doing fine there.

However, I am not sure if it's okay to enter the United States again from Sweden in terms of passport validity. I am confused about the six-month rule. Subtracting six months from the expiry leads to 20th July 2018 as the last date of legal travel sort of. So, I am a bit worried if it would be fine to enter the United States on say 13th or 14th of July 2018 (roughly a week away from the six-month validity).

Looking for suggestions/help ASAP. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Citizens of India (and, in fact, *most* countries) are exempt from the U.S. rule that they must have a passport valid for 6 months after their intended stay. So you should not need to worry.

(The current list of exempted countries seems to be [this one](https://www.cbp.gov/sites/default/files/assets/documents/2017-Dec/Six-Month%20Club%20Update122017.pdf). The linked document is an update dated December 2016; apparently there is no official way to verify it is the *most recent* update, but it is the one everyone seems to link to).